# set first text on UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

i want to set first text on my UISearchBar -the text is "Search"-, and the text will disappear when user start typing.
just like this:

[image]
[image]

how it could be.???
thanx

Answer (score 45, accepted):

use `placeholder` property to set your grayish text that get disappears while text is written on it

```
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"search"]
```

Answer (score 2):

that's the placeholder text, you can set it in Interface Builder, or programmatically with UISearchBar's placeholder property